# How to render a 7 minutes video duration but only play 4 minutes and then stop but total length of video is still remain 7 minutes with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, render, edit

How to render a 7 minutes video duration but only play 4 minutes and then stop but total length of video is still remain 7 minutes when i uploaded it to youtube, just like this image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJDrp.png)

I try `nullsrc` fillter but it didn't success,it's still play entire 7 minutes to end video not 4 minutes
I had researched google but i didn't have a clue, then is there a way to do it?

Comment: I would create a 3 minute video from a single image, clip your video at 4 minutes and then concatenate the 3 minute video.

Comment: I don't quite understand yet. Can you please explain more detail? Thank you.

Comment: What i mean on question is video has totally stop and end just like in the image when i upload it on youtube and play it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need streams of unequal lengths, and will have to stop ffmpeg from duplicating frames to match audio length.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 240 -i color -i 7-min-audio -vsync vfr out.mp4
```